# How does the distorted_inputs() function in the TensorFlow CIFAR-10 example tutorial get 128 images per batch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I was going through the CIFAR-10 example at [TensorFlow getting started guide for CNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html)

Now in the train function in **cifar10_train.py** we get images as

```py
images,labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()
```

In the `distorted_inputs()` function we generate the filenames in a queue and then read a single record as

```py
 # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
 filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

 # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
 read_input = cifar10_input.read_cifar10(filename_queue)
 reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)
```

When I add debugging code, the `read_input` variable contains only 1 record with an image and its height, width, and label name.

The example then applies some distortion to the read image/record and then passes it to the `_generate_image_and_label_batch()` function.

This function then returns a 4D Tensor of shape `[batch_size, 32, 32, 3]`  where `batch_size = 128`.

The above function utilizes the `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` function when returns the batch.

My question is where do the extra records come from in the `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` function? We are not passing it any filename or  reader object.

Can someone shed some light on how we go from 1 record to 128 records? I looked into the documentation but didn't understand.

Comment: I had the exact same question, glad I found this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`tf.train.shuffle_batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch) function can be used to produce (one or more) tensors containing a batch of inputs. Internally, `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` creates a [`tf.RandomShuffleQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#RandomShuffleQueue), on which it calls [`q.enqueue()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue) with the image and label tensors to enqueue a single element (image-label pair). It then returns the result of [`q.dequeue_many(batch_size)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.dequeue_many), which concatenates `batch_size` randomly selected elements (image-label pairs) into a batch of images and a batch of labels.

Note that, although it looks from the code like `read_input` and `filename_queue` have a functional relationship, there is an additional wrinkle. Simply evaluating the result of `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` will block forever, because no elements have been added to the internal queue. To simplify this, when you call `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`, TensorFlow will add a [`QueueRunner`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#QueueRunner) to an internal collection in the graph. A later call to [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners) (e.g. [here in `cifar10_train.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d5f0ac61fe4e4160fbb68d8031418528111dae9/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py#L97)) will start a thread that adds elements to the queue, and enables training to proceed. The [Threading and Queues HOWTO](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html) has more information on how this works.

Comment: Thanks, This cleared up the things a lot. So the queuing works like you first create a flow of how things will go on and then you just say GO to  threads and they will start running and fetching and working on the data whether from the filenames, records or any place else. Am I thinking right.

Comment: That's pretty much all there is to it. (The queue runners also have some support for shutting things down cleanly, by propagating `close()` calls when a `tf.OutOfRangeError` is raised.)

Comment: This is a great topic, but I'm still confused. How does tf.train.start_queue_runners() or tf.train.shuffle_batch() know how to read the files in the queue and how to transform them? It does not seem that the distorted_inputs() function ever gets called again - only once to generate an example image. I ask because I modified the code to read from PNG files and a .txt with labels. It seems to read the images sequentially, but only reads the first label.

Comment: The `distorted_inputs()` function is a little subtle: it returns two symbolic tensors (`images` and `labels` that take a different value each time they are evaluated). Therefore, although the function is only called once, if you run multiple steps (for example, by calling `sess.run([images, labels])`, or by passing them to an op that uses a queue runner like `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`) they will fetch subsequent records from the file(s).

Comment: How exactly do they take different values, and how is it that the transformations get applied each time? I have put the labels in a different file, how can I get the file incorporated into this process?

Comment: The [reading from files HOWTO](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files) has some details about how preprocessing works. The support for joining two files is somewhat limited, but you might be able to achieve what you need with the [`tf.train.shuffle_batch_join()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch_join) function.

Comment: I found an article you wrote that I found very useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340489/tensorflow-read-images-with-labels Thank you very much for all your contributions in the community. Just to clarify: any operation that I perform after tf.train.string_input_producer such as tf.image.decode_png and tf.random_crop until tf.train.shuffle_batch will be repeated on every sess.run? It seems strange that we are not explicitly telling tensorflow to run each of these operations in sequence.

Comment: It's slightly more confusing than that - when you start the "queue runners", additional threads will be created that call `sess.run(enqueue_op)` for each of the queue runners. It's *these* calls to `sess.run()` (and *not* the ones in your own code) that cause the ops up to `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` to execute. Sorry if this sounds complicated: we're trying to find ways to simplify all of this!

Comment: Ok it's starting to make more sense, I successfully set up training and testing last night! (with 98% accuracy!). I'm sure it's difficult to balance performance and ease of use. So far tensorflow is miles above any of the other DNN frameworks out there, thank you for your hard work.