# generic input images with labels in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to make a generic input images with labels in tensorflow.
I checked the question [Tensorflow read images with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340489/tensorflow-read-images-with-labels) and write my test code, but there are some errors.

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
    from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

    txtfilename = '/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/data/UCLandUsedImages/UCImage_Labels.txt'

    def read_labeled_image_list(image_list_file):
        """Reads a .txt file containing pathes and labeles
        Args:
           image_list_file: a .txt file with one /path/to/image per line
           label: optionally, if set label will be pasted after each line
        Returns:
           List with all filenames in file image_list_file
        """
        f = open(image_list_file, 'r')
        filenames = []
        labels = []
        for line in f:
            filename, label = line[:-1].split(' ')
            filenames.append(filename)
            labels.append(int(label))
        return filenames, labels

    def read_images_from_disk(input_queue):
        """Consumes a single filename and label as a ' '-delimited string.
        Args:
          filename_and_label_tensor: A scalar string tensor.
        Returns:
          Two tensors: the decoded image, and the string label.
        """
        label = input_queue[1]
        file_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
        example = tf.image.decode_png(file_contents, channels=3)
        return example, label


    # Reads pfathes of images together with their labels
    image_list, label_list = read_labeled_image_list(txtfilename)

    images = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=dtypes.string)
    labels = ops.convert_to_tensor(label_list, dtype=dtypes.int32)

    # Makes an input queue
    input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels],
                                                shuffle=True)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        result = sess.run([input_queue])
```

I want to run the session and have a look at the input_queue, but I got the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-ddf11f8f84bc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced/readUClandUsedImagetxt.py', wdir='/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/VGG_tensorflow_UCMerced/readUClandUsedImagetxt.py", line 69, in <module>
    result = sess.run([input_queue])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 523, in _run
    processed_fetches = self._process_fetches(fetches)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 493, in _process_fetches
    % (subfetch, fetch, type(subfetch), str(e)))

TypeError: Fetch argument [<tf.Tensor 'input_producer_2/Gather:0' shape=() dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'input_producer_2/Gather_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>] of [<tf.Tensor 'input_producer_2/Gather:0' shape=() dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'input_producer_2/Gather_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>] has invalid type <type 'list'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

I checked the value of image_list, label_list, the outputs are right, so what is the problem here?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try removing the square brackets around input_queue in `result = sess.run([input_queue])`, since you want to specify the output feed there as a single tensor, not a list.