# Is there a way to efficiently vectorize Tensorflow ops on images?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

Tensorflow has a great deal of transformations that can be applied to 3D-tensors representing images ([height, width, depth]) like `tf.image.rot90()` or `tf.image.random_flip_left_right()` for example.

I know that they are meant to be used with queues hence the fact that they operate on only one image.

But would there be a way to vectorize the ops to transform 4D-tensor ([batch_size,height,width,depth]) to same size tensor with op applied image-wise along the first dimension without explicitely looping through them with `tf.while_loop()`?

(**EDIT :** Regarding `rot90()` a clever hack taken from numpy rot90 would be to do:

```
rot90=tf.reverse(x,tf.convert_to_tensor((False,False,True,False)))
rot90=tf.transpose(rot90,([0,2,1,3])
```

**EDIT 2:** It turns out this question has already been answered quite a few times ([one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920240/tensorflow-image-operations-for-batches/38922192#38922192)) it seems `map_fn` is the way to go if you want an optimized version. I had already seen it but I had forgotten. I guess this makes this question a duplicate...

However for random op or more complex op it would be nice to have a generic method to vectorize existing functions...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#map_fn).

```
processed_images = tf.map_fn(process_fn, images)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Looks promising !

Comment: I think, the `tf.map_fn` is not a vectorized operation. Underneath, it loops sequentially over the range. You may need to look at [tf.vectorized_map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/vectorized_map)