# Tensorflow confusing error reading images with labels

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to read a set of images and labels for batch training, but I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Here is my very reduced code that reproduces the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg('C:\\Users\\Alex\\Documents\\Programing\\Python\\cs_dataset\\square.jpeg', channels = 1)
image.set_shape([15, 15, 1])
label = np.array([0, 1])
tf.convert_to_tensor(label)

ibatch, lbatch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=1)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op.run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    sess.run(ibatch, lbatch)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

I only used one image in this example.
What is the cause of this error in this simple example?

A related question that didn't help:
[Tensorflow read images with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340489/tensorflow-read-images-with-labels)

Comment: At what lines does this error occur? Also it should be `sess.run([ibatch, lbatch])`.

Comment: @bodokaiser line 16, "sess.run(ibatch, lbatch)". Your fix worked, Thanks!

Comment: @bodokaiser Also, can you post that as a full reply?

Answer (score 0):

If you want evaluate multiple tensors in a `session` you need to pass them in an array `fetches` to `session.run(fetches)`.

So change `sess.run(ibatch, lbatch)` to `sess.run([ibatch, lbatch])` see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client/session_management) for more.