# Convolutional neural networks for 4 channel images (HDR images with 'rgbe')

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Keras has `preprocessing.image.flow_from_directory()` to read the gray scale and rgb image formats. Is there some way i can read HDR images with 4 channels ('rgbe') using keras or similar library? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tried it with 4 channel? I remember a git post, where fchollet added 4 channels to keras.

Comment: I have keras 2.2.0, but i dont see the code change related to that. Could you check and point me to the change. I see we can comment few lines about the checks as  a work around.

Answer (score 1):

The function `preprocessing.image.flow_from_directory()` is a very powerful one. Sadly it has only the two modes you mentioned. I would suggest you two things since there is not a similar library that could work for you:

1. Go from RGBE to RGB and use `preprocessing.image.flow_from_directory()`
2. Checkout this Github [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4664). They talk about keras having preprocessing with 4 channels, I suggest you update keras.
3. If you want to use the E value, because you think it will have importance in your net, just build your own reader. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340489/tensorflow-read-images-with-labels) might help.

Comment: I think if your point 2 doesn't work i will go with point 3. I have keras 2.2.0, but i dont see the code change related to that. Could you check and point me to the change. I see we can comment few lines about the checks as a work around.